# App Engine Entity to Dictionary

Tags: python, google-app-engine, expando

What is a good way to copy a google app engine entity (in python) to a dictionary object?  I'm using db.Expando objects.  All properties are expando properties.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way to do this, depending on what you need to do.

Comment: Hey Nick, I was trying to turn it into some JSON so I could provide it as a REST resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having an entity called `foo` try with:

```
foo.__dict__
```

Comment: this solution gives you everything on the object, for Model objects, user the properties method and for Expando's use the dynamic_properties method

Comment: @Tom Willis - I Believe the "properties" and "dynamic_properties" methods return just the keys, requiring an iteration to get everything copied.  "dynamic_properties" is also a key in the __dict__ object though, so I believe you can do: foo.__dict__['dynamic_properties']

Comment: This is a bad idea - as @Tom says, it'll return all the members of the object, which is not the same as a dict of properties.

Comment: Correction, its: foo.__dict__['_dynamic_properties'] (added underscore)

Comment: @Dutrow A better idea would be to use `properties` and `dynamic_properties` - you shouldn't rely on internal implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

try this. Where "m" is the instance of the Expando you wish to turn into a dictionary.

```
dict([(x,getattr(m,x)) for x in m.dynamic_properties()])
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
db.to_dict(entity)
```

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the Google Cloud Python client library doesn't work quite so gracefully. So this is a quick fix.

```
your_dict = {x: entity[x] for x in entity.keys()}
```

Remember, the strings are passed in and returned as unicode, not basestring.  ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be recursive though

Answer (score -3):

The accepted answer should be:

```
{}.update(entity}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Can you elaborate? Also there is something wrong with your brackets.