# What is the easiest way to convert nested Datastore Entities to a Python dict?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I've tried reading the docs [here](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/datastore/entities.html) and following the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954846/app-engine-entity-to-dictionary) but neither worked.

Here's what I put into datastore:

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': 'f'}}
```

If I query it I get:

```
<Entity('MyKind', 1232141232id) {'a': 'b', 'c': <Entity {'d': 'f'}>}>
```

I'm using [google-cloud-python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/datastore) (which is [recommended](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) in docs) instead of [ndb](https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb) so I can't use:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
db.to_dict(entity)
```

If I try to cast `dict(results[0])` I get:

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': <Entity {'d': 'f'}>}
```

^^ This is almost what I need except for the nested Entity.

Any recommendations for the best way to do this? It seems like there would be a function for this but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found so far was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565257/620699) but not sure if this would break from any edge cases.

```
import json
json.loads(json.dumps(data), parse_int=str)
```

Answer (score 1):

So `Entity` itself inherits from `dict` and adds only a few functions on top

https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/_modules/google/cloud/datastore/entity.html#Entity

Your `json` solution could be fine, but it depends on what the goal is. If you're ultimately just trying to convert to json then it should be fine, but you're not capturing `entity.key` and maybe that's something you want. Also i think `json` will fail for `datetime` objects and foreign keys unless you explicitly handle those somehow.

You probably need to build a util function like this:

```
def _coerce_value(v):
    if isinstance(v, Entity):
        return_value[k] = entity_to_dict(v)
    elif isinstance(v, Key):
        return v.id  # or do something else here
    return v

def entity_to_dict(entity):
    return_value = {}
    if entity.key:
        return_value['key'] = _coerce_value(entity.key)
    for k, v in entity.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, list):  # handle repeated properties                 
            return_value[k] = [_coerce_value(i) for i in v]
        else:
            return_value[k] = _coerce_value(v)
    return return_value
```